# Exclude certain folders and/or certain files image resizer processing pipeline?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, imageresizer

In our ASPNet MVC project we are using image resizer with some pipeline defaultCommands, but these commands may have side effects on some of our static image files, so how can we exclude some folders and/or specific image files from image resizer pipeline?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using defaultCommands, you should use the `Config.Current.Pipeline.RewriteDefaults` event if you don't want to affect all image requests.

defaultCommands is currently implemented like this:

`void PipelineConfig_RewriteDefaults(IHttpModule sender, HttpContext context, IUrlEventArgs e)
        {
            e.QueryString = e.QueryString.MergeDefaults(defaultCommands);
        }`

from: https://github.com/imazen/resizer/blob/2be2ad19788d45fdaedb6d6425f1fba2d0b143cd/Core/Configuration/PipelineConfig.cs#L53-L56

You could check e.VirtualPath to determine whether or not you want to apply your settings.